# Rails - Best practice to have completely two different designs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-deployment

I am pretty new to Rails.

When creating a website where you have the actual website for your company, describing about your product, and a lot more information, but you also need a user panel where he can manage his stuff.

For example a crypto wallet website, you have the actual website, explaining everything, showing information and such, and you have a trading panel that has a completely different design from the website.

In Rails, you have the `application.html.erb` file which structures the whole website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where **yield** renders the current view the user is browsing.

How can you manage completely two different designs with that structure? Is it a better practice to create a completely new rails project for the user panel? Or it is possible to make it all in one project?

Comment: I think you are asking how to use `render ... :layout => "another_layout"`. Look up `rails render layout`.

Comment: I would recommend creating two separate rails applications. You can put any common code into a shared ruby gem. You will probably still end up with some duplication, but security-wise it will be easier to keep things seperate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `application.html.erb` file is considered a "layout" file, and the `<%= yield %>` is where each controller can insert the page content into your overall layout.

You can have two different versions of things by simply adding another file along side `application.html.erb`, named something like `website.html.erb`. Now, in any controller you have, you can simply add to the top, `layout 'website'`, and all controller actions in that controller will use the `website` layout.

Using this, you can do some neat stuff:

- Have two layouts, one for your application (the wallet app itself), and one for your website (the public pages that don't require a user account). Each layout can include different CSS and JS
- Create a controller called something like `static_pages_controller`, which is meant for "static" pages (pages that do not largely change based on the user). For every page you want on the website, just add a controller action and an appropriate template. Tell this controller to use your `website` template like above.
- Because your static pages are going through Rails, you can even check if a user is logged in, and change your content as-needed, so instead of saying "Log In", you can say "My Account"

You can read more about Layouts on the [official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts).

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in one rails application. Use a `static_pages controller` for your marketing sites, and use devise for user authentication.

with devise you can use `before_action :authenticate_user!` for your dashboard controller, to limit access only to logged in users.

You also may want to read Michael Hartls Book about building Ruby-On-Rails applications.
https://www.railstutorial.org

and have a look at Mackenzie Child's 12 in 12 challenge.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-1HCWbu7iU&list=PL23ZvcdS3XPLNdRYB_QyomQsShx59tpc-